# JSON to Java HashMap Object

Tags: java, json, gson

From an api call I am getting this type of data:

```
"value": {
      "technify_id": "1000051500309",
      "product": "{technify_id:'1000051500309',description:'Light weight 100% cotton fabric',id_uuid:'-100005-3008',image:'http://www.wearego.com/image/catalog/acc/lower/LK0060-BK0.jpg',is_configurable:0,manufacturer_id:'1000050',meta_data:{'Yousuf':'Iqbal','bilal':'ahmed'},seller:{id:'1000031127',name:'BNG Distributer'},manufacturer:{id:'100003521',name:'Ego'},meta_description:'',meta_keyword:'',meta_title:'Spring Collection 2016',model:'LK0060-BK0',name:'ELEPHANT PARADE',price:1200.0,product_attributes:[{attribute_id:'10000516',attribute_name:'1 x ELEPHANT PARADE',text:'1 x ELEPHANT PARADE'}],product_categories:['90'],product_url:'asdasd',quantity:10,requires_shipping:0,sku:'LK0060-BK0',sort_order:'1',status:1,store_date_added:'2016-11-24 23:03:57',store_date_available:'2016-03-22',store_date_modified:'2017-11-14 08:15:00',store_id:'100005',store_name:'WearEgo',store_product_id:'3008',tag:'',tax_id:'1000050',updated_at:'14/12/2007',variants:[{id:'1000051500309_5',technify_id:'1000051500309',price:1200.0,sku:'LK0060-BK0',height:'0.2',created_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',updated_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',quantity:22,weight:0.2,weight_unit:'kg',image:'http://prod.technifydev.com/vendor/ego/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (2).JPG',additional_images:[{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (3).JPG',id:'10000523651',variation_id:'1000051500309_5'},{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (1).JPG',id:'10000523652',variation_id:'1000051500309_5'}],product_specials:[],option_values:[{option_id:'1',option_name:'null',option_value_id:'5',option_value_name:NULL}],height_unit:NULL},{id:'1000051500309_4',technify_id:'1000051500309',price:1200.0,sku:'LK0060-BK0',height:'0.2',created_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',updated_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',quantity:22,weight:0.2,weight_unit:'kg',image:'http://prod.technifydev.com/vendor/ego/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (2).JPG',additional_images:[{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (3).JPG',id:'10000523651',variation_id:'1000051500309_4'},{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (1).JPG',id:'10000523652',variation_id:'1000051500309_4'}],product_specials:[],option_values:[{option_id:'1',option_name:'null',option_value_id:'4',option_value_name:'null'}],height_unit:NULL},{id:'1000051500309_3',technify_id:'1000051500309',price:22.0,sku:'LK0060-BK0',height:'0.2',created_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',updated_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',quantity:22,weight:0.2,weight_unit:'kg',image:'http://prod.technifydev.com/vendor/ego/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (2).JPG',additional_images:[{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (3).JPG',id:'10000523651',variation_id:'1000051500309_3'},{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (1).JPG',id:'10000523652',variation_id:'1000051500309_3'}],product_specials:[{date_start:'0000-00-00',price:605.79,product_special_id:'1000055564',date_end:'0000-00-00'}],option_values:[{option_id:'1',option_name:'null',option_value_id:'3',option_value_name:'null'}],height_unit:NULL},{id:'1000051500309_2',technify_id:'1000051500309',price:1200.0,sku:'LK0060-BK0',height:'0.2',created_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',updated_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',quantity:12,weight:0.2,weight_unit:'kg',image:'http://prod.technifydev.com/vendor/ego/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (2).JPG',additional_images:[{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (3).JPG',id:'10000523651',variation_id:'1000051500309_2'},{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (1).JPG',id:'10000523652',variation_id:'1000051500309_2'}],product_specials:[{date_start:'0000-00-00',price:605.79,product_special_id:'1000055564',date_end:'0000-00-00'}],option_values:[{option_id:'1',option_name:'null',option_value_id:'2',option_value_name:'null'}],height_unit:NULL},{id:'1000051500309_1',technify_id:'1000051500309',price:1200.0,sku:'LK0060-BK0',height:'0.2',created_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',updated_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',quantity:11,weight:0.2,weight_unit:'kg',image:'http://prod.technifydev.com/vendor/ego/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (2).JPG',additional_images:[{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (3).JPG',id:'10000523651',variation_id:'1000051500309_1'},{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (1).JPG',id:'10000523652',variation_id:'1000051500309_1'}],product_specials:[{date_start:'0000-00-00',price:605.79,product_special_id:'1000055564',date_end:'0000-00-00'}],option_values:[{option_id:'1',option_name:'null',option_value_id:'1',option_value_name:'null'}],height_unit:NULL}],view_count:'1',weight:0.2}",
      "store_id": "100005",
      "updated_at": 1506033885000
    }
```

as it is clear that in product field data is of type string but we can also see that it is in json format but keys have no quotations and values are in single quote due to which I am not able to convert it from GSON. Is there any way to handle this scenario and extract proper JSON from this type of data?

Comment: you don't have valid JSON

Comment: That looks like JSON, but (due to reasons you already figured out) it is not. Before you deal with ugly parsing issues, could you ask the upstream provider to fix the output?

Comment: @Ravi I know it is not valid json, but we can clearly see that the pattern is json.

Comment: @C-Otto I am using cassandra source connector for kafka and I already have mentioned it to them in issue https://github.com/tuplejump/kafka-connect-cassandra/issues/29
So no, right now I cant ask for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
    String rawdata=" {\n" +
            "      \"technify_id\": \"1000051500309\",\n" +
            "      \"product\": \"{technify_id:'1000051500309',description:'Light weight 100% cotton fabric',id_uuid:'-100005-3008',image:'http://www.wearego.com/image/catalog/acc/lower/LK0060-BK0.jpg',is_configurable:0,manufacturer_id:'1000050',meta_data:{'Yousuf':'Iqbal','bilal':'ahmed'},seller:{id:'1000031127',name:'BNG Distributer'},manufacturer:{id:'100003521',name:'Ego'},meta_description:'',meta_keyword:'',meta_title:'Spring Collection 2016',model:'LK0060-BK0',name:'ELEPHANT PARADE',price:1200.0,product_attributes:[{attribute_id:'10000516',attribute_name:'1 x ELEPHANT PARADE',text:'1 x ELEPHANT PARADE'}],product_categories:['90'],product_url:'asdasd',quantity:10,requires_shipping:0,sku:'LK0060-BK0',sort_order:'1',status:1,store_date_added:'2016-11-24 23:03:57',store_date_available:'2016-03-22',store_date_modified:'2017-11-14 08:15:00',store_id:'100005',store_name:'WearEgo',store_product_id:'3008',tag:'',tax_id:'1000050',updated_at:'14/12/2007',variants:[{id:'1000051500309_5',technify_id:'1000051500309',price:1200.0,sku:'LK0060-BK0',height:'0.2',created_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',updated_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',quantity:22,weight:0.2,weight_unit:'kg',image:'http://prod.technifydev.com/vendor/ego/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (2).JPG',additional_images:[{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (3).JPG',id:'10000523651',variation_id:'1000051500309_5'},{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (1).JPG',id:'10000523652',variation_id:'1000051500309_5'}],product_specials:[],option_values:[{option_id:'1',option_name:'null',option_value_id:'5',option_value_name:NULL}],height_unit:NULL},{id:'1000051500309_4',technify_id:'1000051500309',price:1200.0,sku:'LK0060-BK0',height:'0.2',created_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',updated_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',quantity:22,weight:0.2,weight_unit:'kg',image:'http://prod.technifydev.com/vendor/ego/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (2).JPG',additional_images:[{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (3).JPG',id:'10000523651',variation_id:'1000051500309_4'},{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (1).JPG',id:'10000523652',variation_id:'1000051500309_4'}],product_specials:[],option_values:[{option_id:'1',option_name:'null',option_value_id:'4',option_value_name:'null'}],height_unit:NULL},{id:'1000051500309_3',technify_id:'1000051500309',price:22.0,sku:'LK0060-BK0',height:'0.2',created_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',updated_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',quantity:22,weight:0.2,weight_unit:'kg',image:'http://prod.technifydev.com/vendor/ego/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (2).JPG',additional_images:[{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (3).JPG',id:'10000523651',variation_id:'1000051500309_3'},{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (1).JPG',id:'10000523652',variation_id:'1000051500309_3'}],product_specials:[{date_start:'0000-00-00',price:605.79,product_special_id:'1000055564',date_end:'0000-00-00'}],option_values:[{option_id:'1',option_name:'null',option_value_id:'3',option_value_name:'null'}],height_unit:NULL},{id:'1000051500309_2',technify_id:'1000051500309',price:1200.0,sku:'LK0060-BK0',height:'0.2',created_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',updated_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',quantity:12,weight:0.2,weight_unit:'kg',image:'http://prod.technifydev.com/vendor/ego/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (2).JPG',additional_images:[{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (3).JPG',id:'10000523651',variation_id:'1000051500309_2'},{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (1).JPG',id:'10000523652',variation_id:'1000051500309_2'}],product_specials:[{date_start:'0000-00-00',price:605.79,product_special_id:'1000055564',date_end:'0000-00-00'}],option_values:[{option_id:'1',option_name:'null',option_value_id:'2',option_value_name:'null'}],height_unit:NULL},{id:'1000051500309_1',technify_id:'1000051500309',price:1200.0,sku:'LK0060-BK0',height:'0.2',created_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',updated_at:'2017-09-22 03:44:40',quantity:11,weight:0.2,weight_unit:'kg',image:'http://prod.technifydev.com/vendor/ego/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (2).JPG',additional_images:[{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (3).JPG',id:'10000523651',variation_id:'1000051500309_1'},{image:'http://www.companion.com.pk/image/catalog/festive/soulful-01 (1).JPG',id:'10000523652',variation_id:'1000051500309_1'}],product_specials:[{date_start:'0000-00-00',price:605.79,product_special_id:'1000055564',date_end:'0000-00-00'}],option_values:[{option_id:'1',option_name:'null',option_value_id:'1',option_value_name:'null'}],height_unit:NULL}],view_count:'1',weight:0.2}\",\n" +
            "      \"store_id\": \"100005\",\n" +
            "      \"updated_at\": 1506033880000\n" +
            "    }";

    HashMap<String,Object> stringObjectHashMap = new
            Gson().fromJson(rawdata,new TypeToken<HashMap<String,Object>>(){}.getType());


    //System.out.println(stringObjectHashMap);

    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(stringObjectHashMap.get("product").toString());
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

It is working for me.

Comment: You should set GSON's 'lenient' flag to make sure this continues to work if they change the default settings.